# JSON Parsing in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I would like to parse some JSON data for my iOS Application. My app works at this point but I feel like the current solution that I have right now will not scale if I decide to add more currencies. The app uses a picker view to choose between multiple currencies then makes a URLSession data task to retrieve the JSON Data and parse it. I would like to know if there is a better way of parsing the JSON data based on different currencies.

```
func parseJSON(_ data: Data, currency: String) -> CurrencyInfo? {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  
  do {
    switch currency {
    case "HKD":
      let decodedData = try decoder.decode(BitcoinDataHKD.self, from: data)
      return CurrencyInfo(price: decodedData.bpi.HKD.rate_float, time: decodedData.time.updatedISO)
    case "GBP":
      let decodedData = try decoder.decode(BitcoinDataGBP.self, from: data)
      return CurrencyInfo(price: decodedData.bpi.GBP.rate_float, time: decodedData.time.updatedISO)
    default:
      fatalError()
    }
    
  } catch {
    delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
    return nil
  }
}
```

You see, for each case I have a Decodable struct. I would like to ideally have one struct that handles all of the cases so I don't need to use a long switch statement when I am parsing the JSON. Here is an example of what the struct looks like.

```
struct BitcoinDataHKD: Decodable {
  let bpi: BPI
  let time: Time

  struct BPI: Decodable {
    let HKD: HKD

    struct HKD: Decodable {
      let code: String
      let rate_float: Double
    }

  }
  
}

struct BitcoinDataGBP: Decodable {
  
  let bpi: BPI
  let time: Time

  struct BPI: Decodable {
    let GBP: GBP

    struct GBP: Decodable {
      let code: String
      let rate_float: Double
    }
    
  }
  
}

struct Time: Decodable {
  let updatedISO: String
}
```

The only thing that is different between the struct is the BPI struct which could be "GBP" or "HKD".

This is what the JSON looks like from CoinDesk.

https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/HKD.json

https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/GBP.json

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the following:

```
struct BitcoinData: Decodable {
  let time: ISOTime
  let bpi: [String: CoinInfo]
}

struct CoinInfo: Decodable {
  let code: String
  let description: String
  let rate_float: Double
}

struct ISOTime: Decodable {
  let updatedISO: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single model to parse all your currencies and use `[String:Currency]` as type for `bpi` instead of creating another level `struct/class`.

```
struct BitcoinData: Decodable {
    let time: Time
    let bpi: [String:Currency]
}

struct Time: Decodable {
    let updatedISO: String
}

struct Currency: Decodable {
    let code: String
    let rateFloat: Double
}
```

**Note:** use ***camel-case*** for naming your variables. Example: Use `rateFloat` and `rate_float`.

Since the key in the JSON data is snake-cased, there are 2 options,
**1.** Implement `enum CodingKeys` like,

```
struct Currency: Decodable {
    let code: String
    let rateFloat: Double
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code
        case rateFloat = "rate_float"
    }
}
```

**2.** or you can set `JSONDecoder's` `keyDecodingStrategy` to `convertFromSnakeCase` while parsing, i.e.

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase //here...
    let response = try decoder.decode(BitcoinData.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the `bpi` data as a dictionary instead to be able to use a common struct. When dealing with currency rates it is much better to use Decimal than Double for the decimal part so I am using the string representation of the rate and convert that to Decimal with a NumberFormatter .

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let bpi: [String: BitcoinPriceIndex]
}
```

I ignored the other properties at the top level to focus on the importan part. Below is the struct that holds the rates and it has a custom init so we can convert to Decimal

```
struct BitcoinPriceIndex: Decodable {
    private static var rateFormatter: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }

    let currencyCode: String
    let rate: Decimal

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currencyCode = "code"
        case rate
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        currencyCode = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .currencyCode)
        let rateStr = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .rate)
        rate = BitcoinPriceIndex.rateFormatter.number(from: rateStr)?.decimalValue ?? 0
    }
}
```

and the decoding part

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    let rates = result.bpi.values
    for rate in rates {
        print(rate.currencyCode, rate.rate)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> USD 10309.7535
> GBP 7841.9078

---

In the above solution the rate property gets set to 0 if the formatter fails, another solution is to fallback to the double value in that case.

Add it to the `CodingKeys` enum (but not as a property)

```
case rate_float
```

and change the decoding in the `init` to

```
if let rateFromString = BitcoinPriceIndex.rateFormatter.number(from: rateStr)?.decimalValue {
    rate = rateFromString
} else {
    rate = try container.decode(Decimal.self, forKey: .rate_float)
}
```